# Why does the view property of a UIViewController doesn't autoresize the containerView?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, subview, xcode4.5, autoresize

I am using containerView. Many things are strange about the containerView.

One of the strange thing is that the type of the view is just UIView. So, what's the different between this view and all the other subViews out there?

Then I started setting things up after reading a bunch of sample code.

```
[self.ContainerView addSubview:self.listBusinessViewController.view];// initialize'
```

At that time, self.listBusinessViewController is already a child of the self. So self have 3 children.

What's surprising is the the frame size of the self.listBusinessViewController.view remain the way I set that up in the xib rather than automatically resized to the ContainerView.

If I do this:

```
[self.ContainerView addSubview:self.listBusinessViewController.view];// initialize'
PO(NSStringFromCGRect(self.ContainerView.frame));
PO(NSStringFromCGRect(self.listBusinessViewController.view.frame));
PD(self.listBusinessViewController.view.autoresizingMask);
PD(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

I got:

```
NSStringFromCGRect(self.ContainerView.frame): {{0, 48}, {320, 412}}
NSStringFromCGRect(self.listBusinessViewController.view.frame): {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
self.listBusinessViewController.view.autoresizingMask: 18
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight: 18
```

so, ContainerView has a height of 412
The listBusinessViewController.view has a height of 480
The autoresizingMask is 18, which is expected. It means that it has flexible width, height, and inflexible border.

So why the listBusinessViewController.view's height doesn't become 412, like it's superview?

I can, of course, do this the high handed way using

```
CGRect frameOfAllChild = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.ContainerView.frame.size.width, self.ContainerView.frame.size.height);
for (UIViewController * child in self.childViewControllers) {
    child.view.frame=frameOfAllChild;

}
```

Code ubber alles (at least ubber xib). However, the whole point of having flexible height and width is so that the view fill out it's superview or it's windows.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `self.ContainerView` doesn't compile. http://sscce.org

Comment: @H2CO3 presumably `ContainerView` is the name of the outlet / property that is pointing to the container view added in the xib or storyboard.

Comment: I am sorry. Yes jrturton is correct. I guess that's where using descriptive name. H2CO3, did you try to actually compile questions code? I am impressed with your dedication.

Comment: @H2CO3 has a compiler in his head, but it hasn't been upgraded to use ARC or xibs / storyboards yet ;)

Comment: @jim thio I haven't actually tried to compile it, but I'm sure it wouldn't compile, because Cocoa (Touch) naming convention prohibits capitalizing firts letters of properties and methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a view to a superview does not change the frame of the added view. A view will only resize its subviews if it is resized *whilst* the subviews are present.

In storyboards, the container view can be used with an embed segue to directly add the content of another view controller. Here the contained view controller is laid out in a frame matching the size. In xibs (where I haven't used them, I must confess) they are not much more than placeholders to aid with layout. You would need to resize the frame of your child view controller's view before adding it. After that, resizing the container will resize the subviews.

Your final code snippet is better written as

```
child.view.frame = self.ContainerView.bounds;
```

Comment: That means all this time we can use containerView designerView design if only we bother telling the childViewControllers when they appear, disappear, etc.

Comment: I think the autoresizing is simply overriding the frame size setting.  Not sure what PO() and PD() do.  Autoresize and manually setting frame size are not compatible options. RTM